# Text asking me to verify if my email is using IE on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I just received a text asking me to put in a verification code if my email address is using IE on Windows 7.  Why would I receive this?

Comment: A guess: phishing attempt to exploit a flaw in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually log in to your mailbox using IE on Windows7 recently? If you enabled 2-step verification for you email, this normally happens every time you log in from a new environment. If not, someone else is trying to hack your email, change your password immediately!
this link might be relevant to your case
[About 2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744?hl=en)